Force R to annotate axes with integers (not decimal numbers)
When I plot integers, the axes are nevertheless annotated with decimal numbers:
plot(1L:3L, 1L:3L)


Can I force R to only display integers?
I do not want to manually specify the numbers, e.g. by using axis(..., at=1:3, ...)!

Best you can do is plot(1L:3L, 1L:3L, xaxp=c(range(1:3),2), yaxp=c(range(1:3),2)) I don't think there is a way in base plot for that. In ggplot2 you can do something like: ggplot() + geom_line(aes(1L:3L, 1L:3L)) + scale_x_continuous(breaks = function(x) unique(floor(pretty(seq(min(x), (max(x) + 1) * 1.1))))) + scale_y_continuous(breaks = function(y) unique(floor(pretty(seq(min(y), (max(y) + 1) * 1.1)))))

@M-- I don't see what the first two "duplicates" have to do with my question. Please explain.

As I explained in my comment, you cannot achieve that within base plot. The first dupe tells you why (data cannot be accessed through plot object). The second one shows the approach for changing axis labels (exactly what you are trying to avoid, but the only way possible). That was only added to help future readers see the solution, but the first one should be enough for you (if data is not accessible, then you need to do it manually). Unless you are willing to deal with ggplot which I also added a dupe target for that and included a snippet in my comment.

Besides that, I wanna point out something; your question is a valid one and a good question, hence my upvote. But that doesn't change the fact that what you're after is not possible for the reasons explained in the main dupe target. Moreover, I very well can be wrong about this being a dupe. So, I won't object to someone else's reopen votes. Cheers.
